# How to multiple select on query SQL?

Tags: sql

these are my table on my database :

```
- transaction :         
  id_transaction        
  type                                 
  paid_off                            
  time  

-details_transaction_product :       
 id_details__transaction_product      
 id_transaction                       
 id_product                          
 price_product                              

-product :       
 id_product       
 product_name
```

NB :

`type` value is `product` or `service`

`paid_off` value is `Yes` or `No`

what i want to know is how to multiple select then get the output like this :

```
Product Name         Product Price
aaaa                  20000
bbb                   30000
```

the data of product that can be shown is `paid_off = Yes`, `time = 1` (by month),

Comment: Please provide test data.

Comment: What is the data-type of column `time` in database table `transaction` ? Are you using MySQL ?

Comment: @Abra it using timestamp

Comment: What does it mean _time = 1 (by month)_ ? Do you mean only for the month of January?

Comment: @Abra yes it is

Comment: @Ellie Are you using MySQL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MySQL, you may use inner join to join 3 tables, then use `FROM_UNIXTIME()` and `MONTH()` to get the month from timestamp.

```
select p.product_name, d.price_product
from product p 
inner join details_transaction_product d
on p.id_product = d.id_product
inner join transaction t
on d.id_transaction = t.id_transaction
where t.paid_off = 'Yes' and MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(t.time)) = 1
```

Comment: Which DBMS has the `FROM_UNIXTIME()` function?

Comment: @Abra nope but i know the right code to use. so it's not a big deal